# UrlHelper.GenerateUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can you provide a sample of using Urlhelper.GenerateUrl within an Action Filter using only the target controller and action ?

Answer (score 40):

```
var url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, "action", "controller", null, RouteTable.Routes, HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, false);
```

**or**

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);    
var url = urlHelper.Action("action", "controller");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Url.Action( Action , Controller )`.

Here an [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/liammclennan/archive/2008/05/21/122298.aspx) to be more clear.

```
<ul>

    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details" , "Reports", new { Id = report.Id })">
        <img src="~/Content/icons/view.svg" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Edit" , "Reports", new { Id = report.Id })">
        <img src="~/Content/icons/edit.svg" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Delete" , "Reports", new { Id = report.Id })">
        <img src="~/Content/icons/remove.svg" /></a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question!